# D3.js placing nodes inside node

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to create a force layout inside force layout nodes

I've created three arrays from the data, 2 for the outer nodes & links and the last one for the inner nodes. And drew the outer chart but I'm not sure how to
create the inner chart for each node.
Should I create a separate simulation for each inner nodes?

I'm adding my current code any help would be grateful!

**data.json**

```
{
  "id": "group1",
  "members": [
    {"id": "member1"},
    {"id": "member2"}
  ],
  "children": [
    { 
      "id": "group2",
      "members": [
        {"id": "member1"},
        {"id": "member2"}
      ],
    },
    { 
      "id": "group3",
      "members": [
        {"id": "member1"},
        {"id": "member2"},
        {
          "id": "member3",
          "children": [
            { "id": "group4" },
            { "id": "group5" }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**main.js**

```
const width = window.innerWidth;
const height = window.innerHeight;
const svg = d3.select("body")
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .call(d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 8])
    .on('zoom', zoomed)
  );

const outerNodes = [];
const outerLinks = [];
const innerNodes = [];
const canvas = svg.append("g");
const simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
  .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-500))
  .force('link', d3.forceLink().id(d => d.id).distance(80).strength(1));

let outerGroup, node, link;

d3.json('data.json').then(data => {
  flatten(data);

  link = canvas.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'links')
    .selectAll('line')
    .data(outerLinks)
    .enter().append('line')
      .attr('stroke', '#777');

  outerGroup = canvas.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'nodes')
    .selectAll('path')
    .data(outerNodes)
    .enter().append('g')
    .attr('id', d => d.id)
    .call(d3.drag()
      .on('start', onDragStart)
      .on('drag', onDrag)
      .on('end', onDragEnd)
    );

  node = outerGroup.append('path')
    .attr('d', generateShapePath())
    .attr('fill', d => d.children ? 'blue' : 'green')

  simulation
    .nodes(outerNodes)
    .on('tick', ticked);

  simulation.force('link')
    .links(outerLinks);
});

function flatten(node) {
  outerNodes.push(node);

  if (node.members) {
    innerNodes.push({parent: node.id, nodes: node.members})
  }

  if (node.children) {   
    node.children.forEach(child => {
      outerLinks.push({ source: node.id, target: child.id });
      flatten(child);
    }); 
  }
}

function ticked() {
  link
    .attr('x1', d => d.source.x)
    .attr('y1', d => d.source.y)
    .attr('x2', d => d.target.x)
    .attr('y2', d => d.target.y);

  node.attr('d', generateShapePath);
}
```

Comment: Have you ever been able to run this code? inconsistent use of missing `generateShapePath` function, missing `zoomed` and `dragXX` functions. What do you expect `generateShapePath` to do?

Comment: How can `group2` and `group3` be an outer node and a child of outer node `group1`? (After `flatten()`). How can you have multiple elements with id's `member1` and `member2`? id's are unique.

Comment: @rioV8 I didn't copy all of the code, just the main parts from it. The outer chart works great, and I've also managed to create the inner chart in one of the nodes but in a very hackish way and it's not working as expected. you can see the demo here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EeYyBZ

Answer (score 1):

You need to decouple all the individual simulations. Model the inner simulations relative to the parent position.

- add a `g` for each node. This `g` will be translated to the node position in the `tick()`
- add the node pentagon to this `g` modeled relative to `0,0`
- for each member do the same: `g` with a relative pentagon `path`
- setup independent drag functions for the simulations => mouse event coords will  be relative
- for the demo I have limited the `width` and `height`
- if you have more nodes with members, like in the question, use a simulation for each group of them.
- what is the use of the `d3.tree`?
- do not use `select` if you want `each`

  ```
  parent.select(d => {
    d.updateMembers = () => {
      innerSimulation.force('center', d3.forceCenter(d.x, d.y));
    }
  });
  ```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
run();

function run() {
const data = {
  "id": "group1",
  "members": [
    {"id": "member1"},
    {"id": "member2"}
  ],
  "children": [
    {"id": "group2"},
    {"id": "group3"},
    {"id": "group4"},
    {
      "id": "group5",
      "children": [
        {"id": "group6"},
        {"id": "group7"}
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const width = 500; // window.innerWidth;
const height = 400; // window.innerHeight;
const svg = d3.select("body")
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .call(d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 8])
  .on("zoom", zoomed));

const outerNodes = [];
const outerLinks = [];
const innerNodes = [];
const canvas = svg.append("g");
const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
const tree = d3.tree().size(height, width);
const simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-500))
  .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(d => d.id).distance(80).strength(1));

const innerSimulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(5))
  .force('collision', d3.forceCollide().radius(10))
  .force('center', d3.forceCenter());

let link, node, nodeGroup;

onLoad(data);

function onLoad(data) {
  flatten(data);

  link = canvas.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'links')
    .selectAll('line')
    .data(outerLinks)
    .enter().append('line')
      .attr('stroke', '#eee');

  nodeGroup = canvas.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'nodes')
    .selectAll('path')
    .data(outerNodes)
    .enter().append('g')
    .attr('id', d => d.id)

    .call(d3.drag()
      .on('start', onDragStart)
      .on('drag', onDrag)
      .on('end', onDragEnd)
    );

  nodeGroup.append('path')
    .attr('d', generatePentagonPath(25))
    .attr('fill', d => d.children ? 'blue' : 'green');

  innerNodes.map(member => {
    const parent = canvas.select(`#${member.parent}`);

    const members = parent
      .selectAll('.member')
      .data(member.nodes)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'member')
      .call(d3.drag()
        .on('start', (d) => {
          if (!d3.event.active) {
            innerSimulation.alphaTarget(.3).restart();
          }
          members.each(d => {
            d.fx = d.x;
            d.fy = d.y
          })
        })
        .on('drag', function (d) {
          d.fx = d3.event.x;
          d.fy = d3.event.y;
        })
        .on('end', (d) => {
          if (!d3.event.active) {
            innerSimulation.alphaTarget(0).restart();
          }
          d.fx = d.fy = null;
        })
      );
    members
      .append('path')
      .attr('d', generatePentagonPath(5))
      .attr('fill', 'orange');

    innerSimulation
      .nodes(member.nodes)
      .on('tick', () => {
        members.attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`);
      });
  });

  simulation
    .nodes(outerNodes)
    .on('tick', ticked);

  simulation.force('link')
    .links(outerLinks);
}

function onDragStart(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) {
    simulation.alphaTarget(0.5).restart();
  }

  nodeGroup.each(d => {
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  });
}

function onDrag(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function onDragEnd(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) {
    simulation.alphaTarget(0).restart();
  }
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}

function zoomed() {
  canvas.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}

function flatten(node) {
  outerNodes.push(node);

  if (node.members) {
    innerNodes.push({parent: node.id, nodes:  node.members});
  }

  if (node.children) {
    node.children.forEach(child => {
      outerLinks.push({ source: node.id, target: child.id });
      flatten(child);
    });
  }
}

function generatePentagonPath(radius = 25, x = 0, y = 0) {
  const numPoints = 5;
  const points = d3.range(numPoints)
    .map(i => {
      const angle = i / numPoints * Math.PI * 2 + Math.PI;
      return [Math.sin(angle) * radius + x, Math.cos(angle) * radius + y];
    });

  return d3.line()(points);
}

function ticked() {
  link
    .attr('x1', d => d.source.x)
    .attr('y1', d => d.source.y)
    .attr('x2', d => d.target.x)
    .attr('y2', d => d.target.y);

  nodeGroup.attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`);
}

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @rioV8, but although it's working good with two members when I'm increasing the number it breaks out the simulation. I've updated the codepen so you can see what I mean https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EeYyBZ

Comment: In the initial run of the innersimulation add a second tick handler (use a name) `tick.parent`, in here determine a size of an enclosing parent pentagon and assign this to the parent `path` element. In the on-end remove this `tick.parent` handler. Additional problems: you might need to increase the size of your links to the children because the parent pentagon is bigger then the links. The complexity increases rapidly.

Comment: Hello @rioV8, today I found your awesome example and tried to figure out who I could add data to it. In your example it looks like you are using exactly one dataset, which contains the members, the child´s and the inner child´s. Which is a tree dataset if I am not mistaken. How would it look like with 2 or 3 root nodes?